# Magento2 : How to show success message in checkout page on page load

Tags: magento2

Magento2:How to show success message in checkout page on page load.

Comment: I want to add success message on load of checkout page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to override controller action(checkout onepage), and need to add message using message manager like

```
$this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('My Success Message'));
```

Or else you can do that by javascript on load, by adding script on header block, or use jQuery or KO.

Comment: how i can do this using jquery?